# Testing Framework For testing UI Components

Tags: javascript, jquery, maven, automated-tests, ui-automation

I am writing jquery plugins like selectbox, rangeslider etc.. I am planning to do automation test. When I look into it, I find them confusing.

There are frameworks like `TestNG`, `JUnit`, `Maven`, `Gradel` etc..
and on the other side `mocha`, `jasmine` etc..

What is the similarity and difference between them?
Which one is the best to test uicomponents?
or At least the basics which would help me to understand?

@sjethvani Thanks for your reply.

Now I have got some understanding on Browser Automation Tools and Testing Frameworks. Have decided to use Selenium with NodeJs and Mocha. But, Is it possible to test it in all browsers parallelly using a single command line? `mocha test` - command preferably runs it in a single browse or Do I have to loop it inside my test file, to open it in different browsers? Is this the way?

Comment: TestNG , JUnit are unit testing frameworks (languages they support are java/c#/python etc).  While Maven(language : xml) , Gradle(language : groovy) , Ant(language : xml) are build tools used to build project. Moreover mocha and jasmine are unit testing frameworks(language they support is javascript) for javascript . If you want to do UI functionality test , I would suggest you to use [selenium with testng/junit] or [selenium with nodejs+mocha/jasmine]